# API's for printing word documents java

Tags: java, printing, ms-word

Does anyone know of any easy to learn API's for printing word documents? I'm using Apache POI to create and edit the documents but I can't find any documentation on auto printing each document after it is created. I just need an API that is well documented (again, preferably easy to learn but it does not have to be) and does not require the end user to download any SDK's (also preferably no xml required).

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow.*

Answer (score 0):

You could check [JODConverter](https://webbygram.com/opensource/jodconverter/) to try and convert your Word Document to a printable format.

You could try [this](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread/15178.html)

You could (credit-Rob Spoor):

- Store your Word file in a temporary file (File.createTempFile())
- Use java.awt.Desktop and its **PrintFile(File)** method
- Delete the temp File

But, you should really be more specific in your question and show evidence of personal effort and research.

Comment: Yeah I probably should've mentioned what I've found. I'll remember that for next time.